# I cannot install VMware horizon client

Tags: vmware

I get this problem when I try to install VMware, I tried installing python2 and gtk module but still it does not fix the problem

Extracting VMware Installer...done. Unable to load gtk: No module named gtk, falling back to console.   100% The system is up to date.  Nothing has been modified.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu and have you messed with python?

Comment: Ubunto 20.04 , python seems to be working fine.